# A field has no "zero divisors"

Tags: proof-writing, field-theory

Question:

Assume $x, y$ are elements of a field $F$. Prove that if $xy = 0$, then $x = 0$ or $y = 0$.

My thinking:

I am not sure how to prove this. **I can only use basic field axioms.** Should I assume that both x and y are not equal to 0 and then prove by contradiction or should I assume one of x and y is not 0 and then prove the other one has to equal 0?

Thanks

Comment: What are your **basic field axioms**?

Comment: Additive inverse, multiplicative inverse, additive identity, multiplicative identity, commutativity, associativity, distributivity

Comment: (https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Field_has_no_Proper_Zero_Divisors)

Comment: If $x,y$ are non-zero then they are inversible, so that $x \times y=0$ is inversible. But  $0$ doesn't have an inverse since $\forall z, \ z \times  0 = 0$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hint:

If $x=0$, then we are done.

If $x\ne 0$, then $x^{-1}$ exists. Multiply $x^{-1}$ to both sides of $xy=0$.

Comment: Would I even have to asses the scenario when y does not equal 0?

Comment: No. If $x=0$, then the statement $x=0$ or $y=0$ is true. If $x\ne0$, we can prove that $y=0$ and hence  the statement $x=0$ or $y=0$ is true. As we have already considered all possible cases. The proof is completed.

Comment: When you say if x = 0, then we are done, does that mean xy = 0?

Comment: If $x=0$, then the statement $x=0$ or $y=0$ is obviously true.

Comment: There are only two possible cases: (1) $x=0$, (2) $x\ne0$. Given that $xy=0$, if we have $x=0$ or $y=0$ in both cases, then the statement is correct. In case (1), $x=0$ or $y=0$ is automatically true. So we only have to work on case (2).

Answer (score 1):

First prove for any element $a $ that $0*a=0$:

$0*a = 0*a +0=$

$0a+0a -0a =(0+0)a-0a =$

$0a-0a=0$.

Let $x\ne 0$ and $y\ne 0$.  Then $x^{-1},y^{-1} $ and $g= (y^{-1}x^{-1})$ exist.

$(xy)*g=(xy)* (y^{-1}x^{-1})=1\ne 0$.

Thus $xy\ne 0$

So $xy=0$ only if $x$ and $y $ aren't both non-zero.

Comment: Assuming you have the axiom that $1\ne 0$.  If you *dont* have that axiom, you can prove that if $1=0$ then for any $a $ in the field $a=1*a=0*a=0$ so the field is "trivial" with only one element, 0.  Which makes this statement trivial.  If xy=0 then x and y are both 0 because 0 is the only element.

Answer (score 0):

In a field every nonzero element has a multiplicative inverse. If $x \neq 0$ there is an inverse let us say $t$, and $xy =0$ so $t(xy)=t0=0$ or $(tx)y=0$ or $1 \times y=0$ which shows $y=0$. Similarly if $y$ is not zero we can show $x$ is zero using the multiplicative inverse of $y$.

Comment: True.  But one also needs to prove that t0=0.  That is not a given.

Comment: Ok $0\times t= (1-1)\times t = t-t=0$