# Proof of statement about invertible matrices raised to the power k

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

True or false?

Let $A$ be a matrix of size $n \times n$. If there is a natural number $k$ such that $A^k$ is invertible, then $A$ is invertible.

I intuitively understand that this is correct, but I would like to know what the formal proof for this statement is…

Thank you!

Comment: One idea is to use determinants, noting that $\det(A^k) = \det(A)^k$

Comment: Hint: $I = A^kB = AA^{k-1}B$.

Answer (score 2):

If $A^k$ is invertible then $\det (A^k)\ne 0$. But $\det(A^k)=\det(A)^k$ (since [a field has no zero divisors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2299678/a-field-has-no-zero-divisors), so $\det(A)^k\ne 0$ or $\det(A)\ne 0$, meaning $A$ is invertible.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If the eigenvalues of the matrix $A$ are $\lambda_1,\cdots ,\lambda_n$, then the eigenvalues of matrix $A^k$ would be $\lambda_1^k,\cdots ,\lambda_n^k$