# How to prove that 2 points $\varepsilon$ and 2$\varepsilon$ are indistinguishable not only in sole case? (Smooth infinitesimal analysis)

Tags: infinitesimals, synthetic-differential-geometry

There are 2 points on the Real line: $A$ and $2A$. They are indistinguishable in sole case - if $A$ is $0$.
But how to prove that $\varepsilon$ and 2$\varepsilon$ are indistinguishable not only in sole case? ($\varepsilon$ is infinitesimal)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can find in e.g. Section 3 of [O'Connor's SDG notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/0805.3307), the real line object $R$ of Smooth Infinitesimal Analysis satisfies the following: $$\forall x \in R.~x \neq 0 \rightarrow \exists y \in R. xy = 1$$

This means that if you can prove that some number $x$ is not equal to $0$, then you can find its multiplicative inverse $x^{-1}$ such that $x x^{-1} = 1$.

It follows that if $\varepsilon$ is a nilsquare infinitesimal, so that $\varepsilon^2 = 0$, then you cannot ever hope to prove that $\varepsilon \neq 0$. Why?

Assume you could somehow prove that $\varepsilon \neq 0$. Then, by the result above, you could find its multiplicative inverse $\varepsilon^{-1}$ satisfying $\varepsilon \varepsilon^{-1} = 1$. And once you found the multiplicative inverse, you could

- Start from the equation $\varepsilon \varepsilon = 0$;
- multiply both sides by $\varepsilon^{-1}$ to get $\varepsilon\varepsilon\varepsilon^{-1} = 0 \varepsilon^{-1}$;
- simplify using $\varepsilon\varepsilon^{-1} = 1$ to $\varepsilon = 0 \varepsilon^{-1}$;
- use the fact that $0x = 0$ holds for any $x$ to conclude that $\varepsilon = 0$.

So we'd now have that $\varepsilon \neq 0$ and $\varepsilon = 0$, a contradiction.

This means that you cannot distinguish any infinitesimal from zero: to distinguish an infinitesimal $\varepsilon$ from zero, you'd have to assume or prove that it's not zero, i.e. that $\varepsilon \neq 0$. But as we see above, $\varepsilon \neq 0$ would give rise to a contradiction!

In practice, this means that whenever you give a proof, construction or definition starting with "take an infinitesimal $\varepsilon^2 = 0$", your proof/construction/definition has to work even in the case that $\varepsilon = 0$. You can't ever rule this case out in any way.

Now, assume that you could somehow distinguish between $\varepsilon$ and $2\varepsilon$, i.e. you could somehow prove that $2\varepsilon \neq \varepsilon$. Then, since $x \neq y$ implies $x - c \neq y - c$, we'd have that $2\varepsilon - \varepsilon \neq \varepsilon - \varepsilon$, i.e. $\varepsilon \neq 0$. But that cannot be shown, as we've seen above.

Not only can you not distinguish infinitesimals from zero, but you cannot distinguish infinitesimals from each other at all. So whenever you give a proof, construction or definition starting with "take an infinitesimal $\varepsilon^2=0$", your proof/construction/definition has to work exactly the same way for every infinitesimal. You won't be able to make distinctions like "if I picked infinitesimal $a$, do something; if I picked infinitesimal $b$, do something else".

---

*aside*: The key thing that makes this work is the use of intuitionistic logic. If we were using classical logic, by the law of excluded middle we'd have that "$\varepsilon = 0$ or $\varepsilon \neq 0$": the second case yields a contradiction, so we'd conclude that the first case, $\varepsilon = 0$ holds, and therefore we'd conclude that the [only nilsquare number in a field is zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2299678/a-field-has-no-zero-divisors). That's why Smooth Infinitesimal Analysis cannot work using classical logic. Thanks to intuitionistic logic, we don't have the law of excluded middle, so it need not be the case that "$\varepsilon = 0$ or $\varepsilon \neq 0$" holds, and Smooth Infinitesimal Analysis keeps working.

As a side remark, I'd like to point out that Smooth Infinitesimal Analysis is a particularly difficult setting for mastering intuitionistic logic.

When one learns constructive mathematics that relies on intuitionistic logic, one finds that certain argument forms and constructions one is used to no longer work. This naturally takes some getting used to. However, there's at least no *new stuff* to keep track of: at least initially, you're still learning largely the same mathematics, you just have to work a bit harder to prove your theorems.

This happens in Smooth Infinitesimal Analysis too. But you also get something more. Smooth Infinitesimal Analysis has *anti-classical* axioms, forms of reasoning that *wouldn't work at all* in classical logic (they'd yield contradictions), but happen to work in intuitionistic logic. So when you learn intuitionistic logic and SIA at the same time, you're forced to grapple with the fact that your old familiar tools no longer work, and you also have to master new tools that look like they shouldn't work. Most people find managing these interactions fairly tough.

Comment: @ Z. A. K. "Now, assume that you could somehow distinguish between $ε$ and 2$ε$, i.e. you could somehow prove that 2$ε$$≠$$ε$..." if $ε$ $≠$ $0$ then 2$ε$ = $ε$ if $ε$ = $0$ and 2$ε$ is indistinguishable from $ε$ if $ε$ is indistinguishable from $0$. Is it right?

Comment: Yeah, we do have $\varepsilon=0$ precisely if $\varepsilon=2\varepsilon$. So if we could show that $\varepsilon\neq 2\varepsilon$, we'd have managed to distinguish between $\varepsilon$ and zero.

Comment: Hello. I read about dual numbers. They have $\varepsilon^2=0$ with $\varepsilon \neq 0$. I used your assumption $\varepsilon \neq 0$ in your proof above and inequality $\varepsilon \neq 0$ was false but as I mentioned in dual numbers $\varepsilon \neq 0$. How is it possible? Thanks. @Z. A. K.

Comment: @Mike_bb: The dual numbers superficially resemble the real line of Smooth Infinitesimal Analysis, but ultimately the two structures don't have much in common. In SIA you are allowed to divide by any number $x$ that is non-zero ($x \neq 0$) - the real line of SIA forms a field. In the dual numbers, this is not the case: there is a dual number $d \neq 0$ so that you cannot divide by $d$.

Comment: How to prove for dual numbers that $\varepsilon \neq 0$ using your proof above? Thanks. Z. A. K.

Comment: @Mike_bb: The proof above doesn't work for dual numbers, and is not needed for them. The dual numbers are just 2x2 matrices that have the form [[a,b],[0,a]] where $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ - the usual set of real numbers from classical calculus, not the real line of SDG! The zero dual number is just the zero matrix [[0,0],[0,0]]. The nilsquare dual number $\varepsilon$ is the matrix [[0,1],[0,0]], which is not equal to the zero matrix simply because their entries are not the same, in particular $0\neq 1$. It does not have an inverse because its determinant is $0\cdot 0+1\cdot 0 = 0$.

Comment: Hello. Is following proof (indeed it's your proof above with more details) correct?

Let $\varepsilon^2=0$ and so we have two cases: $\varepsilon=0$ and $\varepsilon \neq 0$. For the second case we have only infinitesimal $\varepsilon$ that indinistinguishable from zero, and for this case $0$ isn't solution because we have condition $\varepsilon \neq 0$ that must holds. Is it true? @Z. A. K.

Comment: @Mike_bb: Sorry to disappoint, but I won't be able to help with your question this time. The question was already asked on the site, and was closed, meaning the community thinks it should not be answered. I certainly don't want to get on the bad side of the mods by essentially circumventing this judgment. But there's another serious reason too: a month ago I said we're near the point where asking/answering these questions becomes a bad use of time. Now we're past it. I outlined my reasons [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4800117/645935) in the bad news part; my recommendation stands :(

Comment: Hello. Why do you start your proof with assumption $\varepsilon \neq 0$? If we use intuitionistic logic and pick e.g. $\varepsilon \neq 7$ then we'll obtain that $\varepsilon$ is indistinguishable from $7$. Where is my mistake at this point? Thx. @Z. A. K.

Comment: @Mike_bb: No, you don't get the required contradiction if you start with $\varepsilon \neq 7$. To get the contradiction, you need the multiplicative inverse, and to construct the multiplicative inverse you use the implication $x \neq 0 \to \exists y \in R. xy = 1$ (which holds, as noted above). The analogous implication $x \neq 7 \to \exists y \in R. xy = 1$ is _not_ true, so there is no way to use the assumption $\varepsilon \neq 7$ instead of $\varepsilon \neq 0$.

Comment: Hi. Isn't there mistake in your proof on the second line (multiply both sides by $\varepsilon$ to get $\varepsilon\varepsilon\varepsilon^{-1} = 0 \varepsilon$)? How did you get $\varepsilon^{-1}$ ? Thx. @Z. A. K.

Comment: Oops, it does look like a bunch of $~^{-1}$s were missing, which resulted in a wrong argument. I'm not sure when I introduced that problem. I edited it just now, so it should be fixed, please check that it makes sense to you as written now.

Comment: All right now! @Z. A. K.

Comment: Hello. I want ask you about case with $\varepsilon \neq 7$ again. If I start proof with $\varepsilon \neq 7$ then I can say that there is only $\varepsilon=0$ that satisfies $\varepsilon^2=0$ but there is no non-zero infinitesimal $\varepsilon$. At this point I can say that $\varepsilon \neq 7$ is false because there is no non-zero infinitesimal $\varepsilon$ in this case and non-zero infinitesimal is indistinguishable from $7$.Where did I go wrong in my reasoning? Thanks. @Z. A. K

Comment: Is it true that:
1. If $\varepsilon \neq 7$ then we get $\varepsilon=0$
2. If we want to get non-zero infinitesimal then we use $\varepsilon \neq 0$ and get it.
?

Comment: @Mike_bb: Alas, I don't quite understand your question/argument as written. It's probably better to ask it separately, where you can write a proper exposition of your thoughts unburdened by character limits, and other people will be able to chime in with answers and clarifying questions.